# just curious ... better way copy/clone part of an ArrayList?

Tags: java, collections

Is there a more efficient/quicker/more sensible to copy part of an ArrayList than the way I'm doing it?

```
 public ArrayList<FooObject> getListOfFlagged() {    
        for(FooObject fooObject: foos) {
            //for each item in the original array, where the item isFlagged...
            if(fooObject.isFlagged) {
                someOtherArray.add(fooObject);
            }
        }    
        return someOtherArray;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Collections2.filter()` method from `guava`. It'll look more functionally:

```
    Collections2.filter(foos, new Predicate<FooObject>() {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(FooObject input) {
            return fooObject.isFlagged();
        }
    })
```

The result is backed by your original `foos` collection, so if you need a copy, then you have to make a defensive copy with `new ArrayList<FooObject>(filteredCollection)`.

Comment: As the filtered collection does not store a copy of the flagged elements, in most cases it will use less memory than the original code. But every access to the filtered collection will iterate through the backing `foos` collection. So it'll take much more time to access elements. I guess you can say: use this if you are concerned about RAM but can waste CPU.

Answer (score 1):

Using Guava:

```
    class FooObject{boolean isFlagged(){return true;}}      
    List<FooObject> foos = Lists.newArrayList();
    Lists.newArrayList(
        Iterables.filter(foos, new Predicate<FooObject>(){
            @Override public boolean apply(FooObject input) {
                return input.isFlagged();
            };
        })
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

No there is not, unless you know something particular about the position of the elements you need to copy.

Say, you need to copy elements 10-19 of an array of 50 elements, then allocating an array of 10 element and using `System.arrayCopy()` will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

One important optimization is to pre-allocate the number of elements in "someOtherArray", because otherwise it'll do many re-allocations -- of course, depending on how many items you're dealing with. As we don't know the resulting size in advance, the simplest way is to set the capacity of `someOtherArray` to the size of `foos` using

```
someOtherArray.ensureCapacity(foos.size());
```

Of course this will not make sense if `foos` is huge and only a few items are typically flagged.

Also note your method should probably clear() someOtherArray first.

The other optimization I can think of is how the elements of `foos` are accessed. You could try to use a typical `for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)` loop and initialize `fooObject` with `foos.get(i)`. That way is likely to be faster if the "extended for" is implemented by getting a copy of the elements in an array, or possibly also if getting an iterator. But I would think that iterating over an ArrayList receives special optimization in the compiler... Maybe others have experience in that field.

Comment: in my answer I tried to keep access efficiency of the returned ArrayList, while reducing the time and garbage collector workload during creation of the returned list.